# Why my pc returns gray/black screen during Kali Linux upgrading process

Tags: apt, kali-linux, upgrade

I downloaded Kali Linux 2020.2 64-bit live iOS from kali.org, so I boot from USB drive 16GB.  After the booting I did the update:

```
sudo apt update
```

It was successful then I typed

```
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

for upgrade.

The upgrade process lasted more than 10 hours yet my pc turn black screen at the middle of the upgrade process with only blinking mouse and underscore at the top left corner of my pc.

I've clicked the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to return to command environment then

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg
rm -r updates
```

to remove all files in the folder.

My question is how can I upgrade Kali Linux without my computer turning a black or blue screen after many hours.

Comment: It might be caused by a hardware issue. Try using a different USB drive or even a different installation device.

Answer (score 1):

The upgrade process of course wasn’t supposed to last for so long ...
Anyway if you downloaded the latest update from kali.org it should require a very small amount of upgrades or no upgrades at all

However
You can try :

sudo apt-get upgrade

and :

•check the packages will be upgraded (usually it asks a question to start the upgrade process where it show all packages that will be upgraded)

•and if anything seems wrong in terminal upload a screenshot to specify your problem

Hope I helped

Comment: Yeah I've tried the command sudo apt-get upgrade and it took so much time in hours and still return a black screen. I've searched on Google and  I've almost tried all the suggestions yet no positive change. Sudo apt full-upgrade -y I got this command from kali sit still no positive change.

Comment: Please read last two bullets in my answer try to specify what happens after the command does the process run normally and just take time ?or nothing happens ??